# How do I know if my data fit a Poisson Distribution using R?

Tags: r, glm, poisson

I have a dataset of around 30 values and I would like to know if these data fit a Poisson distribution. 
I would like to perform a test, like GLM for my data and I found out that they don't follow a Normal distribution. One of my guesses is that they follow a Poisson distribution, but I need to make sure that it is true.

Comment: Take a look at the `fitdistrplus` package ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/fitdistrplus.pdf)), and [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best) on Cross Validated for a worked example.

Answer (score 4):

You could try a *dispersion test*, which relies on the fact that the Poisson distribution's mean is equal to its variance, and the the ratio of the variance to the mean in a sample of n counts from a Poisson distribution should follow a Chi-square distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom.

You could implement in R like this:

```r
dispersion_test <- function(x) 
{
  res <- 1-2 * abs((1 - pchisq((sum((x - mean(x))^2)/mean(x)), length(x) - 1))-0.5)

  cat("Dispersion test of count data:\n",
      length(x), " data points.\n",
      "Mean: ",mean(x),"\n",
      "Variance: ",var(x),"\n",
      "Probability of being drawn from Poisson distribution: ", 
      round(res, 3),"\n", sep = "")

  invisible(res)
}
```

This allows you to reject the null hypothesis that your data are Poisson distributed if the p value is <0.05. If the p value is *above* 0.05, you could accept that the data followed a Poisson distribution.

Suppose I have the following data:

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- rpois(30, 1)
x
# [1] 0 1 1 2 0 2 3 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 2 1 1 4 1 2 3 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 2 0
```

Then I can just do:

```r
dispersion_test(x)
# Dispersion test of count data:
# 30 data points.
# Mean: 1.066667
# Variance: 1.098851
# Probability of being drawn from Poisson distribution: 0.841
```

A word of warning however. With a sample size as small as 30, one cannot say with any confidence that your data are Poisson distributed. If my next data point turned out to be a 7, then p value would fall below 0.05 and I would have to reject the null hypothesis that my data were Poisson distributed.

Comment: Hi Allan, your function should be function(x).. i think it is a good check for whether it is over dispersed for a poisson

Comment: I am thinking about cases where it is under-dispersed, but of course, there's too little data with 30 to make a good judgement.

Comment: @StupidWolf thank you! I've changed to an x.

Comment: @StupidWolf the dispersion test is two-tailed. If you run the above function with under-dispersed data it will give you a low p value.

Comment: @StupidWolf like `dispersion_test(c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2))` gives p = 0.012